# Declaration is incompatible

Tags: c, embedded, workbench, iar

I was working with IAR Embedded Workbench, using C language.

I had some trouble while dividing my project into the usual main/.h/.c form.

For example, if i create an example.h

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H
void function(int [], int);
#endif
```

And than an example.c

```
#include "example.h"
void function (int[] array, int number)
{number = 1; //code
}
```

It says:

```
Error[Pe147]: declaration is incompatible with "__interwork __softfp 
void function(int *, int)" (declared at line 4 of  (path)

Error[Pe141]: unnamed prototyped parameters not allowed when body is       present  (path)


Error[Pe020]: identifier "number" is undefined  (path)

Error while running C/C++ Compiler
```

Comment: `int[] array`??? This is C, not Java!!! In addition, you say you're using the "usual .h/.c form", then where in the C file do you include the corresponding H file?

Comment: Sure it isn't. But that's not the way to tell it. Chill out. For the c file, just look.

Comment: In `example.h` your use of `#ifndef EXAMPLE_H` is unnecessary, you can declare a function prototype as many times as you like, providing they are all the same.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It is still a good practice, as the header file will most likely contain a little bit more than this single function declaration (I believe that its name - example.h - implies this fact in a pretty obvious manner). And in any case, it has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use wrong syntax. Look at

```
void function (int array[], int number)
{  number = 1; //code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in `void function(int [], int)`. Change to `void function(int name[], int)` or `void function(int *, int)`. Another error is in `int[] array` - it has to be `int array[]` or `int * array`.

Comment: `void function(int [], int);` isn't the problem. It's actually valid C.

Answer (score 0):

In IAR, you will see this error when declaration and definition will not be matching.
For Ex- if you declare your variable as __ro_placement in .hpp and during initialization in .c or .cpp, if you will not provide __ro_placement with variable, IAR will throw same error.